# JavaScript speed monitoring tool?

Tags: javascript

First I'd like to say that I did my research and haven't found any tools that do what I am looking for.

So my question is, is there a tool that records how the JS performs on a website? For example, I am working on a plugin and I am making various changes, but I need some feedback in order to decide if I am actually making optimizations or not. A simple monitoring of the time it takes to execute the JS file would be perfect.

So anyone know such a tool?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! Just a note - Firebug, Page Speed and the other plugins that some of you recommended weren't what I was looking for. For example, Firebug only showed the time spent on network requests, while I needed JS execution time. Anyway, I found what I was looking for and thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Firebug & Yslow, Would also recommend to check out [dynatrace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) tool.
The free edition of the tool can help to measure page loading, rendering, javascript method execution times.
Full list of capabilities can be found @ http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/content/capabilities.aspx.

Comment: Thanks, dynatrace is really what I was looking for, even a bit of an overkill. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Both [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (the extremely popular addon for Firefox) and Web Inspector (built into Chrome and Safari), the *de facto* web development tools for each browser, include complete performance profilers.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.profile();
...
console.profileEnd();
```

should actually be the simplest form.

[YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/) and [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/index.html) as plugins for Firebug (for example, I think there is an extension for Chrome as well, or you can install Firebug Lite on Chrome) can also prove useful (if you haven't found them already).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebug or Yslow or Page Speed. These are firefox addons.

A list of JS tools is also available here, choose which one suits your needs:[http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/02/08/50-extremely-useful-javascript-tools/](http://JS%20Tools%20-%20Smashing%20Magazine)

Hope this helps.